# Skype "couldn't find" USB camera on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, skype, logitech-webcam

First ever post on Stack Exchange, although I have been using it for a long time.

I'm trying to help a friend get a Logitech Messenger USB webcam working on her Windows 7 Professional (update 1) system to use with Skype. I'm a Linux man, so not a Windows expert (or even user) by a long shot, although I've had to deal with it at work enough that I had a fighting chance.

I made some headway, but it still isn't working. The current state is:

In going to Skype -> Tools -> Options -> Video settings, where I would expect to be able to select the webcam, it says "Skype couldn't find a webcam ..."

In "Device Manager", there is:
--Other Devices
----Camera

--Sound, video, and game controllers
----Camera
----Realtek High Definition Audio

--Universal Serial Bus Controllers
----Logitech USB Camera (Messenger)
----(Long list of other things)

I don't know what the first two instances of "Camera" are, but I've confirmed that if I pull the USB camera out of the USB port, the Logitech entry disappears, and reappears when plugged back in.

Now if I look in Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Devices and Printers, I see a index of icons for Devices, Printers and Faxes, and "Unspecified". Under "Unspecified" it gives only "Camera" -- by default the Camera icon has some sort of alert symbol (I'm working from mobile phone photos of the screen here, I didn't snap that one). If I select this camera and go to Camera Properties, there are two tabs, General and Hardware.

If I go into Hardware, I get a list of the two Cameras and the Logitech device as listed in the Device Manager. Logitech is last on the list. I can move Logitech up to the top of the list if for the other two "Cameras" I select Properties -> Drivers -> Disable. Upon doing this, the icon in the Devices and Printers -> Unspecified panel no longer has an alert symbol. That said, in the very bottom of the window, when single-clicking on "Camera" in this window, at the very bottom it says "Camera" and "Model: Camera" and "Category: Audio", which is a little puzzling.

If I now go to Properties -> General, I get "This device is working properly".
Clicking on the "Driver" tab gives among other things that the Driver Date is 27/05/2005, but clicking on "Update Driver" (from the web) confirms that the driver is up to date (I had earlier installed the drivers from the Logitech website as part of this effort). The driver version is 8.4.7.1032, Provider is Logitech.

In the Camera Properties -> General tab, however, it gives
Manufacturer: Unavailable
Model: Camera
Model Number: Unavailable
Categories: Audio Device
Descripton: Unavailable

What am I missing? All of the online resources I could find had to do with installing/updating drivers, finding the right panel to select the device in Skype, etc. The problem here seems to be that the system fundamentally does not recognize the Logitech USB camera as the installed video device to use, and I cannot figure out how to rectify this.

Comment: Do you get a picture if you go on a webcam testing website?

Comment: What is the model number of webcam. Please share the model number, it seems like correct driver is not installed.

Comment: @Matthew Williams, I wasn't aware of a webcam testing website -- I'll look it up next time. I searched high and low for any other software on the computer that might use the cam, in vain.

Comment: This one will probably do you: http://www.testmycam.net/. Lots more on Google to help you out :)

Comment: @user2301394, the physical camera had no other identifying information on it -- just a Logitech logo! I'd hoped "Messenger" was correct, and sufficient -- I've found it online as a "Quick Cam Messenger", so it probably is.

Comment: Thanks Matthew! I'll give it a go, hopefully today (just woke up here in Oz).

Comment: Thanks again Matthew Williams and user2301394 -- I assume after further searching that the model number is V-UBC40. I did try the testmycam.net, and was sure to "allow" it, at several stages through-out the session today, all in vain again. Further detail in a comment to @Mr. Jack's answer below ... Thanks again for your effort.

Comment: You can test your webcam with [test my webcam](http://www.test-cam.com)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the driver itself from Windows doesn't work with the device you connected (or there is a conflict). If you downloaded the official driver/software from the logitech website http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/webcams or from the CD, make sure you install the right version of it, usually they have for XP, Vista, Win7 (sometimes missing for old devices), also they might have 32 or 64 bit version (right click on My Computer -> Properties and check if your Windows has 32 or 64 bit).
Also, you might try installing the driver with the device connected or disconnected, or uninstall it first, disconnect, install the drivers/software then connect. Do not disable the device, this will change only the device's "state".

Comment: Thanks @Mr Jack, I'll try a few more permutations with the drivers and device when I go back out again. I had asked if she has a disk (she didn't), and Windows didn't seem to have anything natively, so I used some auto-detect tool of some sort to grab it from the website. Maybe it did indeed get it wrong. I'll try doing it all manually next time, but ... would the system indicate that it was functioning properly if the drivers were wrong?

Comment: So the machine is Windows 7 Professional. I uninstalled the driver installation from yesterday, and manually downloaded and installed drivers from the Logitech website, both with and without the camera installed. The software suite that contained the drivers (LWS 1.10) also contained a webcam software package, so I could try to test with this as well as the [link](testmycam.net) website. The drivers installed this way were apparently identical in every detail to the ones that I auto-installed yesterday. I think we're up the creek -- Probably time to replace the 8-year old cam! Thanks all!

Comment: You might give another try and when the window shows options to either install automatically or search by your self, choose the second one and point the location to the files you downloaded, specifically there should be a path like `/general_cam_software_folder/drivers/versions/specific_version`, in case the drivers have different version, check the folder where you downloaded the files or the installer extracted them.